# Ocaml homework need some advices

Tags: algorithm, ocaml, set

> We have N sets of integers A1, A2, A3 ... An. Find an algorithm that returns a list containg one element from each of the sets, with the property that the difference between the largest and the smallest element in the list is minimal

**Example:**

```
IN: A1 = [0,4,9], A2 = [2,6,11], A3 = [3,8,13], A4 = [7,12]
OUT: [9,6,8,7]
```

I have an idea about this exercise, first we need sort all the elements on one list(every element need to be assigned to its set), so with that input we get this:

```
[[0,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,1],[6,2],[7,4],[8,3],[9,1],[11,2],[12,4],[13,3]]
```

later on we create all possible list and find this one with the difference between smallest and largest element, and return correct out like this: `[9,6,8,7]`

I am newbie in ocaml so I have some questions about coding this stuff:

1. Can I create a function with N(infinite amount of) arguments?
2. Should I create a new type, like list of pair to realize assumptions?

Sorry for my bad english, hope you will understand what I wanted to express.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is about the algorithmic part, not the OCaml code.

You might want to implement your proposed solution first, to have a working one and to compare its results with an improved solution, which I now write about.

Here is a hint about how to improve the algorithmic part. Consider sorting all sets, not only the first one. Now, the list of all minimum elements from all sets is a candidate to the output.
To consider other candidate output, how can you move from there?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to answer your questions, rather than comment on your proposed solution. (But I think you'll have to work on it a little more before you're done.)

1. You can write a function that takes a list of lists. This is pretty much the same
   as allowing an arbitrary number of arguments. But really it just has one argument
   (like all functions in OCaml).
2. You can just use built-in types like lists and tuples, you don't need to create or
   declare them explicitly.

Here's an example function that takes a list of lists and combines them into one big long list:

```
let rec concat lists =
  match lists with
  | [] -> []
  | head :: tail -> head @ concat tail
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the routine you described in the question to get you started. Note that
I did not pay any attention to efficiency. Also added the reverse apply (pipe)
operator for clarity.

```
let test_set = [[0;4;9];[2;6;11];[3;8;13]; [7;12]] 

let (|>) g f = f g

let linearize sets = 
  let open List in sets 
    |> mapi (fun i e -> e |> map (fun x -> (x, i+1) )) 
    |> flatten |> sort (fun (e1,_) (e2, _) -> compare e1 e2)

let sorted = linearize test_set
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach does not sound very efficient, with an `n` number of sets, each with `x_i` elments, your sorted list will have `(n * x_i)` elements, and the number of sub-lists you can generate out of that would be: `(n * x_i)!` (factorial)

I'd like to propose a different approach, but you'll have to work out the details:

1. Tag (index) each element with it's set identifier (like you have done).
2. Sort each set individually.
3. Build the exact opposite to that of your desired result!
4. Optimize!

I hope you can figure out steps 3, 4 on your own... :)